# Wrong canonicalization (c14n) made by SignedXml - it removes line breaks (&#13;) - is it a .NET bug?

Tags: c#, xml, digital-signature, signedxml, c14n

We are receiving signed xmls from third parties which are using java. Our .NET implementation validates correctly the signatures, except when the xml contain the **&#13;** character reference.

It looks like .NET removes that line break character somewhere in the process of c14n.

I have run some tests in c# with the next xml:

```
var xml = "<a>something&#13;\nsomething\r\n</a>";
```

Using the next code for c14n:

```
    public static void c14n(string xml)
    {
        using (MemoryStream msIn = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)))
        {
            var t = new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform(false);
            t.LoadInput(msIn);
            var o = t.GetOutput() as MemoryStream;
            var c14n = Encoding.UTF8.GetString((o as MemoryStream).ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine(c14n);
        }
    }
```

will result in the next xml, which is accordingly to [w3org](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml-exc-c14n/) specifications (each line ends with LF char):

```
<a>something&#xD;
something
</a>
```

However, when using the next code to see what canonical form has the xml which is signed with SignedXml .NET class:

```
public static void SignXml(string xml)
{
    var doc = new XmlDocument { PreserveWhitespace = true };
    doc.LoadXml(xml);

    var cspParams = new CspParameters { KeyContainerName = "XML_DSIG_RSA_KEY" };
    var rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

    var signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);
    signedXml.SigningKey = rsaKey;
    var reference = new Reference { Uri = "" };

    var env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
    var excC14NTransform = new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform(false);
    reference.AddTransform(env);
    reference.AddTransform(excC14NTransform);
    reference.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
    signedXml.AddReference(reference);
    signedXml.ComputeSignature();
    var c14n = Encoding.UTF8.GetString((excC14NTransform.GetOutput() as MemoryStream).ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine(c14n);
}
```

will result in a different xml (each line ends with LF char), and we can see that the line break (&#13;) was removed:

```
<a>something
something
</a>
```

Is there a way of using SignedXml class so that the correct canonical form to be used? Could be the xml parsing (when creating XmlDocument) the cause of this issue?

I wonder if that's a bug in .NET, and whether there is a workaround for it.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: no - at least not in .net framework; maybe something was changed in .net core...

Comment: I can confirm that nothing has changed. The problem is still there in .NET 6

Comment: Hi there, we have the same issue. Does anyone found a way to be able to sign those xml messages with C# ?